# rail track data of the UK as arcs (lines consisting of lat long points)

Tags: data-request, geospatial, geocoding, space

I am looking for a free/open data source for rail tracks of the UK network (the rail network as arcs - lines). I have all the train station points as lat long pairs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UK open data site has datasets for both stations (which you have) and what they call the centre-lines of the railway track for the network. It is in a shapefile.

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/railway-network-inspire

http://inspire.misoportal.com/geoserver/transport_direct_railnetwork/wfs?amp;version=2.0.0&SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=1.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=transport_direct_railnetwork:railnetwork&SRSNAME=EPSG:27700&outputFormat=shape-zip

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be even available as shape file - see comment. Excellent!

Comment: Csetzkom - good to hear you were able to find what you need!

Comment: only pain is that it is in easting northing - bit more work (-:

Comment: All these links seem to be broken I cannot add the WFS to ArcPro.

Answer (score 3):

OSM data for England could be useful

http://download.geofabrik.de/europe/great-britain/england.html